# Use Google Font with R's Reactable Table

Tags: r, google-font-api, reactable

Following the example [here](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/cookbook/cookbook.html) (Custom fonts) I chose a font that is different enough I could easily see whether it was working or not. [Redressed](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Redressed?selection.family=Redressed&query=redress&preview.text=1234567890&preview.text_type=custom).

Why isn't the body of this table using Google's 'Redressed' font?

```
library("reactable")

# Add a custom font from Google Fonts
# https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Redressed?selection.family=Redressed&query=redress&preview.text=1234567890&preview.text_type=custom
# https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/cookbook/cookbook.html

htmltools::tags$link(href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Redressed:400&display=fallback",
                     rel = "stylesheet")

reactable(
  iris[1:5, ],
  style = list(fontFamily = "Redressed", fontSize = "44px"),
  defaultSorted = "Species"
)
```

Comment: This will only work in e.g. a RMarkdown document but not in an R script or in the console.

Comment: Would this approach work if the Reactable table were part of a Shiny app?

Comment: As far as I get it from the docs: yes. Like a RMarkdown a Shiny App is basically a HTML document.